# Create archive for Custom Post Type : wordpress

Tags: wordpress, loops, archive

I have created an archive.php for my custom post type.

archive-CUSTOM_POSTTYPE.php

Within it I have placed the standard loop.

```
`<?php
get_header();
if (have_posts()) :
while (have_posts()) :
the_post();
the_title();
the_excerpt();
endwhile;
endif;
get_sidebar();
get_footer();
?>`
```

Great! that works.

Where I fall down is when trying to use current_post; and found_posts;

They are not giving me any values when I echo them into the loop.

The actual archive page layout is much more complex and as part of making it work i need the current_post and found_post.

Any IDEAS would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Are you echoing `found_posts` by referencing the global `wp_query` variable? if not, try:

```
echo $wp_query->found_posts;
```